# Copying two images pixel by pixel

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to work with each pixel from depth map. (I am implementing image segmentation.) I don't know how to work with pixels from image with depth higher than 1.

This sample code copies depth map to another cv::Mat pixel by pixel. It works fine, if I normalize it (depth of normalized image = 1). But it doesn't work with depth = 3, because `.at<uchar>` is wrong operation for this depth.

```
cv::Mat res; 
cv::StereoBM bm(CV_STEREO_BM_NORMALIZED_RESPONSE);
bm(left, right, res);
std::cout<<"type "<<res.type()<<" depth "<<res.depth()<<" channels "<<res.channels()<<"\n";// type 3 depth 3 channels 1
cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros(res.rows, res.cols, res.type());
for(int i = 0; i < res.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < res.cols; j++)
        {
                tmp.at<uchar>(i, j) = res.at<uchar>(i, j);
                //std::cout << (int)res.at<uchar>(i, j) << " ";
    }
    //std::cout << std::endl;
}
cv::imshow("tmp", normalize(tmp));
cv::imshow("res", normalize(res));
```

normilize function

```
cv::Mat normalize(cv::Mat const &depth_map)
{
    double min;
    double max;
    cv::minMaxIdx(depth_map, &min, &max);
    cv::Mat adjMap;
    cv::convertScaleAbs(depth_map, adjMap, 255 / max);
    return adjMap;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

left image - tmp, right image - res

How can I get the pixel from image with depth equal to 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Mat::depth()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) returns value equal to a constant symbolising bit depth of the image. If You get depth equal to for example `CV_32F`, to get to the pixels You would need to use `float` instead of `uchar`.

`CV_8S` -> `char`

`CV_8U` -> `uchar`

`CV_16U` -> `unsigned int`

`CV_16S` -> `int`

`CV_32F` -> `float`

`CV_64F` -> `double`

[`Mat::channels()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-channels) tells You how many values of that type are assigned to a coordinate. These multiple values can be extracted as [`cv::Vec`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec). So if You have a two channel `Mat` with depth `CV_8U`, instead using `Mat.at<uchar>` You would need to go with `Mat.at<Vec2b>`, or `Mat.at<Vec2f>` for `CV_32F` one.

Comment: Thank you, i switched to int, and copying works now! But then i do std::cout << res;//where res is depth map. I see another values, if i print values pixel by pixel

Comment: What did `Mat::channels()` and `Mat::depth()` return to You? You might also try `short int` instead of `int`. Types in OpenCV are not defined very well.

Comment: std::cout<<"type "<<res.type()<<" depth "<<res.depth()<<" channels "<<res.channels()<<"\n";// type 3 depth 3 channels 1

Comment: Well, only things I can think of for You is trying `short int`,checking if You should not change the depth/type of `tmp`, or look for something buggy in Your code.

Answer (score 3):

When your images are of depth 3, do this for copying pixel by pixel:

```
tmp.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = res.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
```

However, if you are copying the whole image , I do not understand the point of copying each pixel individually, unless you want to do different processing with different pixels.

You can just copy the whole image res to tmp by this:

```
res.copyTo(tmp);
```

Comment: Thank you, for answer. My task is not copying, it just sample of problem. My task is work with each pixel individually, for image segmentation. Can i work with pixel through Vect3b as integer, or same primitive type?

Comment: https://github.com/Daiver/scripts/blob/master/ocv/cpp/mystereo/main.cpp line 74 - i use pixel here, works fine if image normilized, but failded otherwise