# How can I know the perspective transform matrix after findHomography

Tags: opencv, matrix, mat, perspective, image-stitching

I'm new to OpenCV, and I'm doing something about image stitching.

In the following code I want to know what the perspective transform matrix is and display the matrix, however I am getting the following errors.

```
//-- Find the Homography
cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(cv::Mat(vec2),cv::Mat(vec1),CV_RANSAC);
cout << H.at(0,0) <<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the matrix, just do `std::cout<<H<<std::endl;`.

To use [`cv::Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) You need to add type of matrix to the argument (it is a template method).
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987799/copying-two-images-pixel-by-pixel/15997640#15997640) for more info about arguments for [`cv::Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at)

Comment: I used `std::cout<<H<<std::endl;`,but it get a break while display H.I was wondering if the Mat H generated by findHomography is some different?

Comment: Break? You mean error or what? You can paste the output if it is hard to describe.

Comment: I mean an interruption. The results in call stack window as follows.> ConsoleApplication1.exe!cv::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & out, const cv::Mat & mtx) line 3543 C++
  ConsoleApplication1.exe!main() line 123 C++
  ConsoleApplication1.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() line 536 C
  ConsoleApplication1.exe!mainCRTStartup() line 377 C

Comment: I see You are using visual studio. There might be some kind of problem with project setup. 

You can check if `H` is not empty, and if `cv::Mat(vec1)` and `cv::Mat(vec2)` have the same types. Otherwise I have no idea why it is complaining. The error message tells nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try H.at <double> (i,j)..its works for me....